# Present View Controller doesn't work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have got the below piece of code :

```
   let title = "You are not connected to DropBox"
    let message = "Please go back to the main page and try to log in again"
    let okText = "OK"

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okayButton)


    if dbRestClient == nil{
        print("please refresh me")
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }`
```

However my alert doesn't show up. I am calling this alert from a View Controller that actually shows on the page so its not the case where my VC is working behind the scene. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: how do you check this 'dbRestClient == nil' ? , as i check your code without condition and it's working fine

Comment: Are you sure dbRestClient is nil?

Comment: @Pyro yeah I am sure because it prints `please refresh me` statement

Comment: @DanielBocksteger yeah I am sure, because it prints the statement

Comment: are you getting any error/warning when presenting ?in which method are you calling this any custom method or default methods?

Comment: @Pyro no nothing at all, although it hits the break point on the line `presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` but doesn't show the alert

Comment: ok, when I try your code in without dbRestClient condition in viewDidAppear it was working, maybe some other conflict with your code

Comment: @Pyro what do you mean by conflict in my code?

Comment: what is your parent view from which you are presenting ?

Comment: @Pyro that VC is my parent controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)** instead.

Should work after adding self.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that, but I guess I didnt. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help out. Happy coding :)